# How to find MHz of ram sticks

Tags: memory, ddr3

I bought some ram sticks at the local computer shop in my town. Trying to upgrade my laptop. however my laptop is 1600 MHz, i do not know how much these sticks are. Is there anyway to find out without installing them into the computer?

Sorry if i am not explaining this right.

Comment: you might want to refer to [this](http://superuser.com/a/703688/270195)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: he's talking about getting specs on RAM that is not yet installed.

Comment: Did you not get any information about the sticks before you bought them? I would ask the shop at least.

Comment: The shop should hopefully have some record of the RAM and your purchase. They might know the specs. Any way you ask them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I've got RAM everywhere. How do I identify it?](http://superuser.com/questions/194638/ive-got-ram-everywhere-how-do-i-identify-it)

Answer (score 2):

Most RAM has stickers or labels on them indicating their manufactured specifications.  If not, they certainly have a manufacturer name and product ID that can be referenced online.  Visually inspect the RAM you want to use.

Comment: They do not have stickers on them at all.

Comment: The PCB must have a burned/printed manufacturing information, at least -- or perhaps the surface of some of the chips.  Can you provide a photo of the RAM?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they dont say on the sticker on the RAM, the best you can do is Google the part number on the sticker.